# A question about the size of the set $E$ in Chebyshev's inequality

Tags: measure-theory

According to my notes, if $f$ is a nonnegative measurable function on $E$, then for any $\lambda \geq 0$:

$m\{x \in E : f(x) \geq \lambda\} \leq \frac{1}{\lambda}\int_E f$

That is Chebyshev's inequality.

My question is, does $E$ have to have finite measure?  Everything in my notes so far specified that $E$ must have finite measure.

Answer (score 1):

No, the proof doesn't need that $E$ has a finite measure. Denoting $M =\{f \ge \lambda\}$ the following holds:
$$m(M) = \int_M 1 \, dm \le \int_M \frac{f}{\lambda}\, dm \le \frac{1}{\lambda} \int_E f \,dm$$